# Retrieve output log when test fails during setup

Tags: selenium, nunit, log4net, specflow

I'm running automated unit tests with SpecFlow and Selenium. SpecFlow offers `BeforeTestRun`, `BeforeFeature`, and `BeforeScenario` attributes to execute code between tests at the appropriate time.

I'm also using log4net to log test output.

When a test fails during the test or during the `BeforeScenario` phase, I can see the output logged.

[image]

But when a test fails during `BeforeTestRun` or `BeforeFeature`, there is no output available.

[image]

This makes it difficult to diagnose when the test fails during the early stages on the remote testing server and all I have are the output logs.

Is there any way to use log4net to get output logs when the test fails before the individual test has begun?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom method, with reference of TestResult and TestContext objects. And you can call it in [TearDown] or somewhere on end of the Test:

```
    if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status.ToString() == "Failed")
    {
     string message = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message;
     string logs = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace;
    }
    else if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status.ToString() == "Passed")
    {
    //User defined action
    }
    else
    {
     string otherlog = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's weird that it doesn't show you log when a tests is failed.
It shows it well for me:
[image]

What I suggest to try is to check that you log4net pushes all the logs to console. Actually if you haven't done some special manipulation, then your logger should by default have a console appender.

I initiate my logger like this:

```
private static readonly ILog log =
            LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Another guess is that maybe when your test fails on OneTimeSetup Fixture it doesn't have any log yet.